# Compute variance of image

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to compute a variance of laplacian of an image without using *opencv* since opencv is quite huge. So, I want to use any other library that has smaller size.

Here is my current code. It works perfectly but using opencv-python-headless:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("images/test.png")
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(image_gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
print(laplacian)
```

How can I get the same result (same laplacian value) using any other library/libraries that has smaller size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using [scipy](http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/) instead with its [laplacian function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.laplace.html).

```
from scipy import ndimage #To compute the laplacian
import imageio #To load the image as a numpy array
import numpy as np #To convert it to gray

#A function to convert your rgb image to gray
convert_to_gray = lambda rgb : np.dot(rgb[... , :3] , [0.299 , 0.587, 0.114]) 

image = imageio.imread("images/test.png")
image_gray = convert_to_gray(image)

laplacian = ndimage.laplace(image_gray).var()
print(laplacian)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convolve your image with the Laplacian kernel:
[image]

For this you could use any library that lets you load the image into a 2D array.
The Python "Pillow"-library could be useful.
Then you just need to calculate the variance of the image.
This has been answered here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938008/variance-and-mean-of-image#:~:text=2%20Answers&text=These%20are%20indeed%20the%20correct,x%20%2D%20mean(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938008/variance-and-mean-of-image#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=These%20are%20indeed%20the%20correct,x%20%2D%20mean(x))).